# Spring Security ApplicationListener<HttpSessionDestroyedEvent> is called on login

Tags: spring-security

I am using Spring Security and I have created a `ApplicationListener` for `HttpSessionDestroyedEvent` (for logout and session expiry events). But this listener's `onApplicationEvent` method is called on login also which looks like a inappropriate behavior. How do I make this working. Below is the code:

```java
public class MySessionDestroyListener implements ApplicationListener<HttpSessionDestroyedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(HttpSessionDestroyedEvent httpSessionDestroyedEvent) {
        httpSessionDestroyedEvent.getSecurityContexts();
        // business logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be prepared to that. The servlet container generally creates a session before the user is connected. When spring-security authenticates the user, it first close that previous session and creates a new one.

That means that an event `HttpSessionDestroyedEvent` is triggered both on login and logout. You can differentiate those 2 kinks on event by storing for example the user name in session. If it is present, the session was a regular one and it makes sense to call your business logic, if not it was just a *technical* one and you shoud just ignore it

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried the approach you mentioned above. I have a AuthenticationSuccessEventListener that is invoked on login success. In this class I am setting user name as an attribute in session. Then I am getting the same attribute in SessionDestroyedEventListener. This attribute is available during login and logout as well. The reason is SessionDestroyedEventListener is called after AuthenticationSuccessEventListener. Could you please suggest if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

If your login page uses a HTTP session in a Servlet 3.0 or older container, the Session Fixation Attack Protection will destroy this session and create a new one (`migrateSession`), see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-session-fixation):

> **Session Fixation Attack Protection**
>
> Session fixation attacks are a potential risk where it is possible for a malicious attacker to create a session by accessing a site, then persuade another user to log in with the same session (by sending them a link containing the session identifier as a parameter, for example). Spring Security protects against this automatically by creating a new session or otherwise changing the session ID when a user logs in. If you don’t require this protection, or it conflicts with some other requirement, you can control the behavior using the `session-fixation-protection` attribute on `<session-management>`, which has four options
>
> - `none` - Don’t do anything. The original session will be retained.
> - `newSession` - Create a new "clean" session, without copying the existing session data (Spring Security-related attributes will still be copied).
> - `migrateSession` - Create a new session and copy all existing session attributes to the new session. This is the default in Servlet 3.0 or older containers.
> - `changeSessionId` - Do not create a new session. Instead, use the session fixation protection provided by the Servlet container (HttpServletRequest#changeSessionId()). This option is only available in Servlet 3.1 (Java EE 7) and newer containers. Specifying it in older containers will result in an exception. This is the default in Servlet 3.1 and newer containers.
>
> When session fixation protection occurs, it results in a `SessionFixationProtectionEvent` being published in the application context. If you use `changeSessionId`, this protection will also result in any `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionIdListener` s being notified, so use caution if your code listens for both events. See the Session Management chapter for additional information.

There are some solutions for that problem:

- don't use session for login page (in most cases not possible)
- update to Servlet 3.1 container
- change the Session Fixation Attack Protection to `none`(not recommended)
- adopt your business logic